# how to obtain process module on remote computers using powershell, Get-Process -Module gives it only for local machine

Tags: powershell, process, remote-server

how to obtain process module on remote computers using powershell, Get-Process -Module gives it only for local machine. basically i want to obtain absolute paths of .dll files that are being loaded/used by processes running on that remote server/computer.

Answer (score 0):

Running `invoke-Command` should work.

`C:\> Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Process -Module} -ComputerName comp1`

You are not able to pass the `-ComputerName` switch to `Get-Process` unfortunately.

`C:\> Get-Process -Module -ComputerName comp1`

Get-Process : Exception getting "Modules" or "FileVersion": "This feature is not
supported for remote computers.".

Comment: Tried Invoke-Cmd, got multiple errors: Cannot enumerate the modules of the "csrss" process.
   + CategoryInfo : PermissionDenied: (System.Diagnostics.Process (csrss):Process) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldnotEnumerateModules,GetProcessCommand AND Select-Object : Exception getting "Modules": "Access is denied" for services CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (System.Diagnostics.Process (services):PSObject) [Select-Object], GetValueInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyEvaluationExpand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: Used Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Modules -outvariable processes | Out-Null}   Again got errors -  Exception getting "Modules": "Access is denied" AND Exception getting "Modules": "Unable to enumerate the process modules." Same as above comment

Comment: **This cmd gives same errors as above but also gives a list of processes though it does not give all modules for each process. just one module per process and its path**  `$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $TargetWinServer
   Enter-PSSession -Session $session
   [System.Collections.ArrayList]$processes= @()
   Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Modules -outvariable processes | Out-Null` **So many .dlls that are blocked by a process still dont come up in the output**

Comment: how to obtain modules that a process running on a remote computer has loaded using powershell???

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process

Are you running PS as admin?

Comment: Cannot enumerate the modules of the "services" process.
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.Diagnostics.Process (s 
    ervices):Process) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldnotEnumerateModules,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
+ PSComputerName

Comment: i am running as admin